# detailed_info on product category pages

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, category-listing

I am using a plugin to add files for download to a product.

This uses the following to load on a product page:

```
<?php foreach ($this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml') as $alias => $html):?>
    <div class="box-collateral <?php echo "box-{$alias}"?>">
        <?php if ($title = $this->getChildData($alias, 'title')):?>
             <h2><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h2>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php echo $html; ?>
    </div>
endforeach;?>
```

I need to then be able to load this information on the list.phtml page so that this information appears for the category pages. So I have added this code block to my list.phtml page as well.

I then added the following to my local.xml:

```
    <layout>
        <catalog_category_default>
            <reference name="product_list">
                <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                </block>
            </reference>
        </catalog_category_default>
    </layout>
```

But the detailed_info is blank for products I know have options. I assume I have missed something!

How do I get this to show on the product pages?